# How to monitor windows service text output

Tags: c#, service, console, windows-services

For my windows service, I have a procedure that outputs log entries to a text file. That all works well, but I can not see it live. As soon as I open the file to see the log, it stops writing to it, because the service can't write to an open file, I'm assuming.

**My question:** Is there a way to monitor this text output with something like the console? This solution will only be used for debugging purposes. I don't want a GUI or anything like that--just something simple to watch what my logger is doing.

Right now to write to the text file I'm doing:

```
RecordDataToLog("Log this");

private void RecordDataToLog(string txtData)
{
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(logFileDir, true))
        file.WriteLine(txtData);
}
```

I tried to use `Console` like this, but it didn't work--no console window showed.

```
Console.WriteLine("Log this");
```

Or is there another text editor or text file type that supports writing to an open file?

Comment: wrong question. you don't need an editor that supports WRITING to an open file. you need one that supports READING an openfile - you do NOT want to be modifying the log file while it's open/being used by yoru app.

Comment: @MarcB Sorry. What I meant was, I want an editor that supports writing (by the service) while the file is open (by me).

Comment: Use Notepad++ and then File > Reload from Disk to refresh the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened the file with notepad and Notepad++ and was still able to write to the file with StreamWriter, so it must be the editor you are opening the file with. Notepad doesn't refresh the contents at all. You need to reopen the file. Notepadd++ should prompt you and ask if you want to reload.

PowerShell v3 includes an option on the Get-Content cmdlet to open a file and print new content as it is added, similar to tail on *nix OSes:

```
Get-Content "C:\path\to\log\file" -Wait
```

Answer (score 1):

You will reduce your pain in this area significantly by using a logging framework, such as [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

These will allow you to configure multiple output formats in a separate configuration file. I've converted a home-grown logging system to log4net. Took about half a day to do this - and this was a relatively large commercial application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Notepad++.

If you start it in the command-line by writing

```
notepad++.exe -ro "MyLogFile.txt"
```

then it will open the file in read-only mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Get-Content cmdlet from PowerShell to tail your log file

Answer (score 0):

You can use also the "monitor" tool of NotePad++ (it's an icon with an eye).. doing so NotePad will automatically show you the updated file every time it will be modified by your app